# Can't type a $ in WebStorm PHPStorm IntelliJ Pycharm Appcode or something else by Jetbrains?

Tags: plugins, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, dollar-sign

If you're using a Jetbrains IDE I just wanted to let you know the solution to a problem that took me forever to find.

## The problem

You just can't type a "$".  Like anywhere. In any kind of file.

#### Example:

You're writing a scss file and you want to define a variable ($var) with a value of 3.

Your goal is thus to write:

```
$var : 3;
```

So you type `Shift + 4,var : 3;` expecting to get $var : 3, but what you get instead is:

```
var : 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

### The solution:

If you're using this plugin:  **[Extended Code Sense](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5026)**<sup>[1]</sup>

- ***Disable and remove it.***

else

- Disable your plugins one by one until you find the source of the problem.

---

<sup>1. It is worth noting that the plugin has not been updated since 2010</sup>